# How to tell if a clause is interpreted perfectively or imperfecitvely?

Tags: meaning, grammar

In *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, they define a perfective clause as:

> a clause describes a situation in a way that considers it as a whole, in its totality, without reference to any temporal structure or subdivision it might have,

while an imperfective clause is defined as:

> a clause describes a situation in a way that makes reference to its internal temporal structure or subdivision.

However, I still find it a little bit subtle to tell what the interpretation of a clause is. Is it about if the situation is finished, since they mark a clause like *She wrote a novel* as perfective and one like *She was writing a novel* as imperfective? How to apply this distinction on more complex constructions, such as the perfect?

Comment: You're quite correct in being puzzled. This is not a grammatical definition at all, but more of the usual handwaving. _Perfective_ and _imperfective_ are terms of art in certain theories of grammar, but not most, and not of English.

Comment: Why do we need such a distinction? What does it help us to do?